# Bytes Processed on Query explanation

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a "costly" query. I would like to optimize it (make it cheaper).
I  ran the query and looked at the explanation which I find pretty useful for optimizing run times.

My problem is as follows: for each stage, I see "Rows", but I do not see "Bytes Processed". As BQ charges by "Bytes Processed", I would like to optimize according to the processed data volume rather than # of records scanned.

My question is: Is there a way to get this kind of info? (Volumes of read data in Bytes for every execution stage that actually reads data)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get this kind of info?

I don't think it is available for us(users)
The Explanation Visualization comes from below part of [Jobs: get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) API

```
"query": {
 "queryPlan": [
  {
   "name": "Stage 1",
   "id": "1",
   "waitRatioAvg": 0.008679262671196536,
   "waitRatioMax": 0.009519650796361627,
   "readRatioAvg": 0.45445465918366207,
   "readRatioMax": 1,
   "computeRatioAvg": 0.1796969833724843,
   "computeRatioMax": 0.2585664334066632,
   "writeRatioAvg": 0.06727424173478641,
   "writeRatioMax": 0.06727424173478641,
   "recordsRead": "37098285",
   "recordsWritten": "37098285",
   "steps": [
    {
     "kind": "READ",
     "substeps": [
```

See more details at [statistics.query.queryPlan](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.query.queryPlan)

> For each stage, I see "Rows", but I do not see "Bytes Processed". As BQ charges by "Bytes Processed", I would like to optimize ...

You most likely know, but wanted to mention
I don’t think the charge is based on sum of all processed bytes across all stages.
Not at all! [more details here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#query-pricing-details)
You're charged according to the total data processed in the columns you select, and the total data per column is calculated based on the types of data in the column.
So, I can be wrong a little, but optimization you are looking for makes total sense in terms of performance, not in terms of charges.

From the other hand - it is blind spot to me - how [billing tier](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute) is exactly calculated? What are the factors? etc.
That is where bytes processed for each stage can potentially be helpful if you know how this drives billing tier - so this is still open question for me :o(

Comment: I would believe there should be correlation between the # of bytes in READ stages. And overall bytes procecced. In most of tier 1 queries, this should correlate with tottal bytes billed. Having said that, it would also be nice to have an indication which step pushed the query to higher tier...

Comment: i am with you on this :o)